# How can I resolve ts(2339) when using keyof typeof on a custom Type?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, typeof, keyof

**The Problem**

The TypeScript at the bottom of this post results in the following error:

> Property 'push' does not exist on type '{ title: string; outline:
> string; why: string; additional: string; }'.ts(2339)

I understand why the error occurs, I just can't figure out how to resolve it. Ideally I'd exclude the `idea` key from the list of possible keys to push to, but I'm not sure how.

**The TypeScript**

```
type Idea = {
    challenges: Array<string>,
    personas: Array<string>,
    experiences: Array<string>,
    idea: {
        title: string,
        outline: string,
        why: string,
        additional: string,
    }
};

let idea:Idea = {
    challenges: [],
    personas: [],
    experiences: [],
    idea: {
        title: "",
        outline: "",
        why: "",
        additional: "",
    }
};

function addtoIdea(ideaItem:string, uniqueId:string){
    idea[ideaItem as keyof typeof idea].push(uniqueId);        
}

addtoIdea("challenges","abcd1234");
```

Comment: `Idea.idea` is not an array, so you'll have to make sure that `idea[ideaItem as keyof typeof idea]` is an array first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you need to first make sure that the property you're trying to `push` into is an `Array` first:

```
type Idea = {
    challenges: Array<string>,
    personas: Array<string>,
    experiences: Array<string>,
    idea: {
        title: string,
        outline: string,
        why: string,
        additional: string,
    }
};

let idea:Idea = {
    challenges: [],
    personas: [],
    experiences: [],
    idea: {
        title: "",
        outline: "",
        why: "",
        additional: "",
    }
};

function addtoIdea(ideaItem:string, uniqueId:string){
    const prop = idea[ideaItem as keyof typeof idea]; // string[] | { ... }
    if(Array.isArray(prop)){
            prop.push(uniqueId); // prop is string[] 
    }    
}

addtoIdea("challenges","abcd1234");
```

[Working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJhAhlAvFA3gWAFBT1AYwAtEAbUiAOwHMIBnALigEEAnVxEAHjuFYEsaAPgA0OfFEis6Ae0qJGLdpx59B1UePwQAHlP5UC9Jmw7deA4WNz5+CREyw2JeYP2AUmF9dZf4ZAK4eghBeajS+flAA7kQgYZbUkX6IcHDu-HJkCT5aeAC+OPkA3Dg4FMBQdkgM8EioGHmEJORUtIoA2gC6yZIQ0lmdPU26+obGUN291Q6Nzi5uHqFQAEQrvRKBwZTLaxv4sfGr600SqeluWaRMe02F2CVl2ABmAZQEl5RQ58AydYgAChmMGAEAAtgxvBEoG9+ABHAIQeCQ8LUACUTgkBDkvEkrBkYAaMw6wNBYO+dCgAGsICAZM8oKBIPSqvYuqV5vxngDTJwAHT8Oi8kAAsD4sBojGnKJigl8sABOhEAGwhFIuBo4oSO7ah5PH5-ewAlbEMgUGj0dYrRAAIwIcAAjAAmADMABYVpqgA)

Comment: Thanks @mike-s I had tried that approach, but went the long way around it (which didn't work).

```if (Array.isArray(idea[ideaItem as keyof typeof idea])){idea[ideaItem as keyof typeof idea].push(uniqueId);}```

Comment: @user2781522 I see ;-) The reason it doesn't work is that typescript cannot infer that `idea[ideaItem as keyof typeof idea]`  is the same property as the one you try to `push` to.

Comment: Yep @mike-s, as soon as I saw your solution I realized that's what was going on. Appreciate the posted clarification!